# Fragments view is null when orientation changed

Tags: android, view, android-fragments

Im having some problems when it comes to porting my app from the normal activity style to the fragment style. Im beginning to notice that when a fragment gets recreated, or popped from the backstack it loses its views. When I say that Im talking about a listview in particular. What im doing is im loading items into the listview, then rotating the screen. When it goes back through, it gets a nullpointerexception. I debug it and sure enough the listview is null.  Here is the relevant code to the fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sg_question_frag, viewGroup, false);

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        list = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sgQuestionsList);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            catId = savedInstanceState.getInt("catId");
            catTitle = savedInstanceState.getString("catTitle");
        }
        populateList(catId, catTitle);
    }
```

And here is how it is called (keep in mind there are a few other fragments that im working with as well)

```
@Override
    public void onTopicSelected(int id, String catTitle) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();

        SGQuestionFragment sgQuestFrag = (SGQuestionFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("SgQuestionList");
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        //If the fragment isnt instantiated
        if (sgQuestFrag == null) {

            sgQuestFrag = new SGQuestionFragment();
            sgQuestFrag.catId = id;
            sgQuestFrag.catTitle = catTitle;
            //Fragment isnt there, so we have to put it there

            if (mDualPane) {
                //TO-DO
                //If we are not in dual pane view, then add the fragment to the second container
                ft.add(R.id.sgQuestionContainer, sgQuestFrag,"SgQuestionList").commit();

            } else {
                ft.replace(R.id.singlePaneStudyGuide, sgQuestFrag, "SqQuestionList").addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        } else if (sgQuestFrag != null) {
            if (sgQuestFrag.isVisible()) {
                sgQuestFrag.updateList(id, catTitle);
            } else {
                sgQuestFrag.catId = id;
                sgQuestFrag.catTitle = catTitle;
                ft.replace(R.id.sgQuestionContainer, sgQuestFrag, "SgQuestionList");
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
                sgQuestFrag.updateList(id, catTitle);

            }
        }
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
    }
```

What I would ultimately want it to do is to completely recreate the activity, forget the fragments and everything and just act like the activity was started in landscape mode or portrait mode. I dont really need the fragments there, I can recreate them progmatically with some saved variables

Comment: You shouldn't look for the `ListView` in the activity if the list it's in the inflated layout in the `onCreateView` method. Use `getView().findViewById...`.

Comment: Im not looking for the listview in the activity, im looking for it in the fragment in the onActivityCreated method

Comment: I dont know if this is what you meant, but I changed getActivity().findViewById to getView().findViewById and it works like a charm, thank you. If you post that as the answer I will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get a reference to a view from within a `Fragment` always look for that `View` in the `View` returned by the `getView()` method. In your case, at the time you look for the `ListView` the `Fragment`'s view probably isn't yet attached to the activity so the reference will be null. So you use:

```
list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.sgQuestionsList);
```